# Error: no such partition grub rescue help

Tags: grubrescue

I had Ubuntu as my only OS (removed windows) and wanted to switch back. I created a bootable USB with Windows 10 and when I rebooted my pc I see the no such partition error. La only returns (hd0) and (hd1). I've tried everything I can find to no avail. So how do I fix it so I can run Windows? I don't have a live Ubuntu disk to load from.

Answer (score 1):

If you currently have Ubuntu running successfully you could always wipe your drive and install Windows 10 over the unallocated space. You would need to prepare before hand by making sure your Windows 10 USB/CD is formatted correctly and can be booted from.

I could be wrong, but I believe you could go into    gparted    and it's probably    /dev/sda    . Otherwise you could run    fdisk -l    to find the main location for your drive and then run    sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M    .

I know this would work for sure from a Live USB/CD, but I'm not 100% about doing this in the actual filesystem. Please take my answer with a grain of salt.

Comment: I forgot to ask, did you already install Windows 10 over Ubuntu or no? If so, are you getting the grub rescue boot screen?